# How to programatically restart explorer.exe using C#

Tags: c#, cmd, explorer

I been trying to restart explorer.exe so my other script that hides the icons can take effect. I tried to do this by executing a command prompt window through my C# program:

```
/k taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

When I run this the first half of it work and the explorer.exe is killed, and my screen is black except the files that were already open, but when the second half of the script is run only the windows explorer (file manager) starts. By the way the above command works if I start cmd on a regular terminal but it doesn't through my C# program. the only way I could turn the explorer back on was using ctl+alt+del to bring up the task manager and run a new task "explorer" no quotation. If you know how to fix this please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should solve the issue:

```
// find all the explorer processes and kill them
Process[] explorer = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
foreach (Process process in explorer) {
    process.Kill();
}

// start a new explorer process
Process.Start("explorer.exe");
```

With this method I did not experience an issue with needing to wait between killing the process and starting it again

Answer (score 0):

```
static void RestartExplorer()
    {
        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "/c taskkill /f /im explorer.exe";

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", strCmdText);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Process.Start(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\..\\explorer.exe");
    }
```